# Iterating through nested dictonaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have the following python which is supposed to loop through all items in a dictionary and correct the formatting of any date it finds.

```
def fix_time(in_time):
    out_time = '{}-{:02d}-{:02d} {:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(in_time.year, in_time.month, in_time.day, in_time.hour, in_time.minute, in_time.second)
    return out_time



mydict={
    'Field1':'Value1'
    'SomeDateField':1516312413.729,
    'Field2':'Value2',
    'Field3': {
        'Subfield1':'SubValue1',
        'SubDateField':1516312413.729
    }
}

for key, value in mydict.items():
if type(value) is datetime.datetime:
    mydict['{}'.format(key)]=fix_time(mydict.get(key, None))
```

My issue is it only seems to correct the date fields at the first level ('SomeDateField' in the example).  Date fields in nested dictionaries are ignored ('SubDateField' in the example).  This is a simple example.  In my environment I have no idea what the input will look like when I receive it.  These date fields potentially could be 3 or 4 levels down.

Any suggestions would be greatly appeciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried recursion? `if isinstance(value, dict): recursion()` where the recursion function runs the same original loop, therefore it will continue to spiral deeper into the nested dict levels

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def fix_recursive(dct):
    for key, value in dct.items():
        if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
            mydict[key] = fix_time(value)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            fix_recursive(value)

fix_recursive(mydict)
```

Not sure if that exactly does the job, but it should be something along those lines...

Comment: don’t post as an answer if you’re not sure it works, defeats the purpose, no?

Comment: If I'm unable to access Python, but see a question that I think I can answer 'freehand'?

Comment: don’t answer it, leave a comment, as you did, the point of an answer is to leave a valid and complete answer, not a guess

Comment: I'll take your advice for next time, thanks. Seems a bit pointless now to take it down, no?

Comment: This actually worked perfectly without any changes needed!  Thanks.